# Variable is defined but not used (But used below)

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template, liquid-template

Shopify indicates an error on the top line of the code that my variable is defined but not use can anyone teach me what's the logic behind it because I used the variable below

```
{% assign compareAtPriceMax = product.compare_at_price_max | times: 1.16 %}
{%- capture price_max -%}
{%-
 render 'price-ui-templates',
 template: 'price-max',
 value: compareAtPriceMax,
  -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
```